# Is there a console command to give vendors gold to help with selling?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Last night, I made enough potions from ingredients in storage to be sold for approximately 900,000 septims. My practice in times past would be to go to fences in round-robin fashion in Markarth, Solitude, Windhelm, and Honningbrew Meadery to sell off items since they have 5,000 septims each. In the interest of saving and not wasting time, I used the command `additem f 495000` on Mallus Maccius `"(0002ba8f)` in the meadery and started selling potions, but once he gave me 5,000 septims, things got weird. Items can still be sold for him like normal, but my gold no longer increases, and his does not decrease below 495,000. The Wikia article [Console Commands (Skyrim)](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Console_Commands_(Skyrim)) has this to say about the command: `Use on a merchant to set the amount of barter gold. This gold may not go to your inventory when selling items to the vendor.`

**Question:** Is there a way to get around this problem? Is there another command or target on which to act that would allow me to accomplish what is being attempted?

**Rejected Answers:**

- Remove the items and give yourself gold for the items **[imprecise on gold calculations or time consuming; also has same problem with leveling up speech]**
- Continue what you are doing but give yourself gold when finished **[while this allows leveling up speech, there is imprecision on gold calculations without being time consuming]**
- Keep going to your fences round-robin style to sell your items **[this is to be avoided; the goal is to save time even if it breaks immersion slightly]**
- Download mod `name_goes_here` so merchants have more/infinite gold **[my internet connection's proxy prevents such downloads; it is extremely inconvenient to access other internet connections]**
- Go to `web_site_url` to read/watch a tutorial on how to accomplish what you are trying to do **[see last point; proxy probably blocks the web site, and it is close to impossible to get a different internet connection]**

Comment: I would also like to point out Skyrim's downright excellent modding community. I use a mod that gives all general stores something in the area of 10-11000 gold, which helps by a lot. I don't remember off the top of my head the name of the mod, but with a little bit of searching, it should come up with on the mod nexus or the Steam workshop.

Comment: @BammaHamma Thank you for trying to help, but please see the fourth rejected answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Open the console, target the merchant by clicking on him and enter `additem f x` where x is 32000 - merchant's current gold. Trading will become buggy if merchant gold exceeds, I believe, 32767, so add enough gold to get him to 32000, sell your stuffs, add more gold if you have more stuff to sell. If his gold exceeds 32000, you can use `removeitem f x` to get him under this number.

Comment: Thank you! Your suggestion was invaluable. I found out the potions were worth closer to 2,330,000 septims. That would have required going to the fences over 465 times. You saved me an enormous amount of time. :-)

Answer (score 2):

This approach works for me:

**How to give a merchant A Lot of Gold**

1. Write down how much gold you have for reference.
2. Give yourself A Lot of Gold.
3. Buy everything the shopkeeper owns
4. Sell it back to him at a tenth or so of the price.
5. Repeat `3` and `4` until you no longer have A Lot of Gold.
6. The merchant now has A Lot of Gold.
7. Set your own gold amount back to the number you wrote down in `1`.

Comment: Of course, the side effect is that this is a very cheaty way to boost your Speechcraft.

Comment: There's a cloud to every silver lining. And if that's a major worry, simply use the console to return your speechcraft skill to its original value.